# How to active payment pane in Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: commerce

I am using Commerce Kickstart and I am trying to configure the checkout process.

But control is not going in payment module. Instead it's going in last step directly.

Can anybody help me find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Commerce Checkout Pane Payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_pane_payment) or [Commerce Checkout Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_co_pages%20module).

```
Commerce Checkout Pane Payment Module Feature:
```

This module creates a Checkout Pane that shows the selected payment method on the review page of the checkout. This is a contrib module for Drupal Commerce.
Drupal Commerce Contrib. This module creates a Checkout Pane that shows the selected payment method on the review page of the checkout.

```
Commerce Checkout Pages Module Feature:
```

Commerce Checkout Paages gives site administrators the ability to create additional pages for the checkout process through the admin user interface.

Comment: i appreciate ur answer, but while in checkout process m not able to view payment pane its jumping direcrtly to last step

Comment: yepp, i installed this module,and its giving me permission to customize panes but,checkout->shipping->review order->payments->order confirmation in these step controll is going upto shipping and directly jumping to last step

Comment: i suggest you to check after adding new page weather it go through the new step or skip

Comment: m using kickstart,

Comment: as usual it checkout process is already there,onlt thing is controll is not going in payment pane

Comment: this part needs to debug i think !!!!!!!!!

Comment: yup, i have installed new kickstart but problem persists in new and old one as well thanx..!

Comment: I have the same problem in commerce kickstart demo version...Is it Fix???